# Are Two Metric Spaces Equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Are the following metrics equivalent on $\Bbb R$?
  $ d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d'(x, y)=|\tan^{-1}(x) -  \tan^{-1}(y)|$.

Comment: You didn't specify the underlying set. Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset math in your question.

Comment: What does equivalent mean? Homeomorphic?

Comment: with $\tan^{-1}$ you mean $\arctan : \mathbb R \to (-\frac\pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta the topology induced by $d$ and the one by $d'$ are the same. Or equivalently, the identity map  $f: (X,d) \to (X,d'), f(x)=x$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

If the basic set is $\mathbb R$, yes they are equivalent. What you have to show is that if $x_n \to x$ in one metric then  $x_n \to x$ in the other. This is obvious because $\tan$ and $\arctan$ are continuous functions in the usual topology.

Comment: Thanks. But one another question is: We know (R,d) is complete, but is (R,d') also complete?

Comment: No. $\{1,2,..\}$ is a Cauchy sequence which is not convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They are equivalent. \In general if $f$ is any continuous increasing bijective function then the metrics defined by $$d(x,y)=|x-y|$$ and $$d'(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$$  are equivalent.